# Where can I find the source code of UIDatePicker of ios4

Tags: ios4

```
Where can I find the source code of  specific widget inside ios4?
```

for exmaple , the code of UIDatePicker ,segment control ...

Thanks advance for your help.

BR,
 camino

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIKit is not open source; the source code is not available.

Answer (score 1):

As Jim said, the source code ad an UIKit element is not available because it isn't open source.
But if you are searching for source code that show **how to use** them, you can search on the [Developer Site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Sample+Code).
[UICatalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) source code is what are you looking for.
It shows how to use the most common UIKit's element, like buttons, pickers, alerts and other...